# Save pdf to my server with TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am new to PHP and I am using TCPDF to generate a PDF from my website. I can download all the files without any problems but when I tried to save it to a folder in my server I found problems. I tried this:

```
    $pdf->Output('../pdf/example_001.pdf', 'F');
```

and I tried this

```
    $filepath = "../../pdf/test.pdf";
    $fp = fopen($filepath, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $pdf);
    fclose($fp);
```

but it gives me an empty file.

Comment: can you see the pdf by connecting to your server with FTP and than download it to your desktop and open with adobe acrobat?

Answer (score 5):

Answering a bit late. You can use the following format to save the file:

```
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/pdf/'.$pdf_name.'.pdf', 'F');
```

The 'F' parameter is used for storing the file in the file system. The `dirname(__FILE__)` helps give relative path, which is important. In this example I am storing the PDF in a folder "pdf" located in the same folder as the file in which I have used the above line. Relative or absolute path folder path is important. `__DIR__` also can be used to locate current directory.

Comment: even later... only the absolute path worked for me.